# Is there any way i can change it into a switch statement?

Tags: java

I need help converting this code into a switch.

```
if(val >= 0 && val < 10) 
    cell[0].plus1();
else if(val >= 10 && val < 20 )
    cell[1].plus1();
else if(val >= 20 && val < 30 )
    cell[2].plus1();
else if(val >= 30 && val < 40 )
    cell[3].plus1();
else if(val >= 40 && val < 50 )
    cell[4].plus1();
else if(val >= 50 && val < 60 )
    cell[5].plus1();
else if(val >= 60 && val < 70 )
    cell[6].plus1();
else if(val >= 70 && val < 80 )
    cell[7].plus1();
else if(val >= 80 && val < 90 )
    cell[8].plus1();
else if(val >= 90 && val < 100 )
    cell[9].plus1();
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Eran's answer is the correct one. In general, if you're reaching for a switch in Java, you need to back up and find where your design has gone horribly wrong.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You don't need a switch statement.

All these statements can be reduced to :

```
if (val >= 0 && val < 100)
    cell[val/10].plus1();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want a `switch`, you can do:

```
int v = val/10;
switch(v) {
case 1: cell[1].plus1();
    break;
case 2: cell[2].plus1();
    break;
case 3: cell[3].plus1();
    break;
case 4: cell[4].plus1();
    break;
case 5: cell[5].plus1();
    break;  
case 6: cell[6].plus1();
    break;  
case 7: cell[7].plus1();
    break;  
case 8: cell[8].plus1();
    break;  
case 9: cell[9].plus1();
    break;  
}
```

But you could simply do (which is equivalent):

```
if (val >= 0 && val < 100) cell[val/10].plus1();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int division = val / 10;
now val >=0 && val < 10 equals division = 0
```

etc...

Comment: Val in this case is a double and its returning an error that it cannot convert from double to int. am stack. public void update(double val) {
            
            
  if (val >= 0 && val < 100)
                    cell[val/10].plus1();

Comment: Thank u Eran.. Finally Got it

Answer (score 0):

Since the cases in a switch statement are determined by equality, an if-else ladder using inequality can not naturally be modelled by a switch statement.

You could list out each of the values in the range and utilize the fall-through nature:

```
switch (val)
    {
    case 0:
    case 1:
    case 2:
    case 3:
    case 4:
    case 5:
    case 6:
    case 7:
    case 8:
    case 9:
        cell[0].plus1();
        break;
    case 10:
    case 11:
    case 12:
    case 13:
    case 14:
    case 15:
    case 16:
    case 17:
    case 18:
    case 19:
        cell[1].plus1();
        break;
    ...
    }
```

This really is not any improvement to your code and quickly becomes very unwieldy.

Since each of your conditions perform the exact same operation (`cell[ X ].plus1()`), all you really need is to handle the relationship between the input `val` and the array index.  As [Eran's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35995602/1172714) shows, in your code this relationship is a simple matter of integer division.  I recommend choosing his answer.